# Acciaccatura vs Appoggiatura in Beethoven

Tags: piano, beethoven, ornaments, editions

While studying the 2nd movement of Beethoven's Sonata Op.90, I found these *appoggiaturas* in bars 28-29.

[image]

This is the Henle edition (which I find to be one of the most reliable editions for Beethoven); the *appoggiatura* can also be found in the 1815 first edition (see [here](http://ks.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/0/0b/IMSLP51271-PMLP01484-Op.90.pdf)).

Based on my knowledge, I thought the two bars would have to be played like this

[image]

but in all major intepretations I listened to, the F and A are played as *acciaccaturas* respectively on the E and G ([here](https://youtu.be/uDzQnkIvCcg?t=396) is an example). 
Does anyone know why everyone performs it as an *acciaccatura*? How did Beethoven intend the two embellishments?

Comment: I've always gone by the rule that, once Mozart moved to Vienna, all appoggiatura are written out and little notes are always acciaccatura (though occasionally played as a very short note on the beat instead of before).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Print Evidence (a.k.a. nobody agrees)

#### Editions that indicate an undecorated (no stroke) grace note

- [Holograph manuscript](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/b/ba/IMSLP51270-PMLP01484-Op.90_Manuscript.pdf) (i.e., Beethoven's handwriting)

[image]

- [First edition](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/0/0b/IMSLP51271-PMLP01484-Op.90.pdf)

[image: First edition mm. 28-29]

- [Schenker](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/e/eb/IMSLP00027-Beethoven,_L.v._-_Piano_Sonata_27.pdf)

[image]

#### Editions that indicate a decorated (with stroke) grace note

- [Gesamtausgabe](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/7/79/IMSLP51799-PMLP01484-Beethoven_Werke_Breitkopf_Serie_16_No_150_Op_90.pdf)

[image: Gesamtausgabe mm. 28-29]

- [Schnabel](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/8/8a/IMSLP502797-PMLP1484-Beethoven_(ed._Schnabel)_.90.pdf)

[image: Schnabel edition mm. 28-29]

#### Editions that clearly agree with you

- Cooper<sup>1</sup>

[image: Cooper edition measures 28-29]

### The Recorded Evidence  (a.k.a. everybody agrees)

"everybody" plays the grace note before the beat (or near simultaneous with the beat)

NOTE: All recordings are from YouTube and are timed to the measures in question.

- [Ashkenazy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLzQbyWfBnY&t=6m30s)
- [Barenboim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrlBtZlCIfk&6m40s)
- [Choi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_wDhiWbISU&t=50) (HieYon)
- [Douglas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCtu3aZ6Sbc&t=52s) (Barry)
- [Gilels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxAeHKE5moM&t=50)
- [Kempf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnTV9OHHbBM&t=52s)
- [Pogorelich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4OG1-biycs&t=9m20s)
- [Pollini](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3L967vbdyU&t=6m6s)
- [Richter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcTHZmUXYzg&t=5m59s)
- [Schnabel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0_arj8Ys3g&6m24s)

### Conclusion: IMO

The performance of the ornament would seem to be a matter of tradition as much as anything else. Though I think we have to pay deference to the fact that all of these great performers, spanning a century, agree with each other that the grace notes precede the beat.

I prefer to play it the way you indicate. Playing an acciaccatura, or playing an appogiatura that precedes the beat, tends to make m. 28 beat 4 sound like a downbeat. I find the meter and melody much more clear and flowing when the ornaments are played as 32nd notes on the beat.

Answer (score -1):

̇
ORNAMENTS IN CLASSIC

> Proposals

> *In early music up to the baroque are the spelling
> n the decorations seldom uniform and regional
> and different for different composers.
> This also applies to the classic and leads to
> that e.g. cannot always make a clear decision
> whether a proposal should be long or short. Times
> are short suggestions as sixteenths, sometimes as eight
> el with flag crossed out or, depending
> from the time signature, also notated as a thirty-second note
> t, long suggestions often as eighth notes, occasionally off
> he
> also as a quarter. It is important to know that
> the crossed flag is not “as short as
> possible ”means, but with
> 16th is to be equated because it is nothing more than an old one
> notation for the 16th.*

Source:

Edition

[www.pian-e-forte.de](http://www.pian-e-forte.de)
**Fachwissen
VERZIERUNGEN
Anmerkungen
zu Ornamenten
in der Klaviermusik**